# Assigning values to a randomly generated assembly

Tags: r

```
suits <- c("clubs", "hearts", "spades", "diamonds")
face <- c("two","three","four","five","six","seven",
          "eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king","ace")

deck <- crossing(suit = suits, face_val = face) %>%
  unite(card, face_val, suit, sep = '-') 


deal <- function(deck, handsize) {
  sample_n(deck, size = handsize, replace = TRUE)
}

deal(deck, 5)
```

So essentially I want to compute the total value for the 5 cards that is generated. So for example the the value for a king would be 10 and ect. What ways would be best to go about doing this. I figure I must somehow assign each specific card a value then go from there to compute.
When I run the function I get a random set of 5 cards.
card

1 ace-clubs
2 seven-spades
3 king-diamonds
4 four-clubs
5 ten-diamonds
for example, then I want to get the total value of the set. So in this case it would be 11+7+10+4+10=42

Comment: write a vector whose names are the cards and the elements are the values. Then subset accordingly

Answer (score 1):

A named vector of values will do nicely here! That allows you to index by the names that you have as output from your "deal" function.

```r
face <- c("two","three","four","five","six","seven",
          "eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king","ace")
values <- c(2:10, 10, 10, 10, 11)
names(values) <- face

hand <- sample(face, 5)
hand_vals <- values[hand]
hand_total <- sum(hand_vals)
```